# Revolution slider stop on click on a link tag

Tags: javascript, onclick, slider

```
<i class="fa-icon-hand-o-right"></i> <a href="#" id="datacenter2" style="color:white;"> Data Center</a>[indeed_popups id=2]
```

*Want to stop this slide when user click in this link "Data Center" after click the slider will stop completely.*